# Offset all timestamps in a text

Tags: windows, web-apps, nlp, timezones

I am looking for a Windows program or webapp that can offset all timestamps in a text by a certain number of hours.

Example: if the input is:

> I am free:
>
> - Tomorrow Wednesday between 4pm and 11pm
> - Thursday between noon and 2pm
> - Thursday between 4:30pm and 11pm

and I want the timestamps to be shifted by -3 hours, the output should

> I am free:
>
> - Tomorrow Wednesday between 1pm and 8pm
> - Thursday between 9am and 11am
> - Thursday between 1:30pm and 8pm

Use case: I sometimes need to change the timezone in which my email is expressed.

Comment: Would a webapp be OK too?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes

Comment: Use a standard calendar, such as MS Outlook, then change the system, clock by 3 hours? ;-)  Personally, I would whip up a quick Python script. Much will probably depend on consistency in your free text - 4 o'clock, 4pm, 4p.m, 16:00 ...